# Understanding python while loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Let's say I have a queue,

```
queue = [1]
```

when i run a while loop that says

```
while queue:
    queue.pop(0)
    print("Hello World")
```

why does this code not terminate and outputs hello world?

Comment: Could you edit your question and show the output?

Comment: It works for me. It should only run once, because `queue` only contains one element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition is tested *before* each iteration of the loop, not after every statement inside the loop body. So even though `queue.pop(0)` empties the list, you still execute the next statement and print the message.

Then it goes back to the beginning and tests `queue` again. This time the condition fails and the loop terminates.

Comment: I didn't even consider that a beginner could have thought this was how loop conditions worked. Good catch.

Comment: He's reading it as English. If someone told you to perform a bunch of steps while the sun was out, you would stop as soon as the sun set.

Answer (score 6):

Because you are already in the loop and the `queue` gets checked only after the print statement again. Also `.pop()` deletes the last value so if you have 1 value in the list just use `.pop()`

Answer (score 0):

Because `queue` is a non zero list. Any non-zero is consider as true. So that is why the `while` loop will continue to run and will not terminate.

However the above is a general concept. For this specific question, your code is working fine.

```
queue = [1]
while queue:
    queue.pop(0)
    print("Hello World")
```

It runs only once.